# Dual-Boot Error. Grub said "Error 18"

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub

For **years** I've been working with my PC having a dual boot windows/linux (Suse 9.3). Today, things have changed. Grub said :

```
Grub loading stage 1.5
Grub loading, please wait...
Error 18
```

and nothing happens.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The wiki at Linux Questions offers some great advice:

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/GRUB#Error_18